# reinstall anaconda without python

Tags: windows, python, anaconda

I need to reinstall my anaconda platform on windows

But I cannot do any kind of `conda update`. Because I cannot run its `python.exe`

My antivirus detected a false positive on `python.exe` of my anaconda installation virtual envirnoment and moved the file out to quarantine.

Do you know if it is safe to remove all the anaconda folders in `c:\programdata\anaconda` and download and install anaconda? or is there anything I should check and remove, maybe in registry or ini files or files in system directories?

Comment: Just a comment, but it might be worthwhile to move any quarantined files back to their original locations and exclude the relevant folders from your antivirus scans. That way, you may (perhaps) be able to achieve several goals -- being able to update Anaconda, being able to uninstall/reinstall through normal means and prevent false positives in the future.

Comment: that's a good idea, thanks